# Cumulative hierarchy

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am currently writing some notes for a course on axiomatic set theory and I wanted to depict a graphic representation of the set-theoretic universe as the big V. Is there some overleaf package/code which you can recommend me?

Comment: Easiest is to include an image such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe#/media/File:Von_Neumann_Hierarchy.svg  harder is to use TikZ. Best though is to expand your questions so that readers can understand exactly what you want. I am not aware of any package.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Thanks!!

Comment: This kind of image is pretty straightforward to make in Ti*k*Z, acually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example of what you can achieve quickly enough in Ti*k*Z, here's the picture of the Von Neumann universe linked in the comments.

[image: Von Neumann universe]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\nangle{50} \def\r{10} \def\mygreen{green!50!black}
        
        \foreach \i/\lbl in {
            1/1,
            2/2,
            3/3,
            4/4,
            5/5,
            8/\omega,
            9/\omega+1,
            10/\omega+2,
            14/2\omega,
            16/3\omega,
            20/\omega\times\omega}          
            {
            \draw[\mygreen, line width=2pt] (90+0.5*\nangle:0.05*\r*\i) arc (90+0.5*\nangle:90-0.5*\nangle:0.05*\r*\i) node[black, below right] (\i) {$V_{\lbl}$};
            }
            
            \path (1) -- (20.-135) node[pos=-0.09] {$V_0$} node[pos=0.275,sloped] {$\dots$} node[pos=0.575,sloped] {$\dots$} node[pos=0.925,sloped] {$\dots$};
        
        \draw[blue, line width=3pt, cap=butt, rounded corners] (90+0.5*\nangle:1.1*\r) -- (0,0) node[yshift=3pt,fill=\mygreen,circle,minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt] {} -- (90-0.5*\nangle:1.1*\r);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time for your answer! It worked perfectly and it looks beautiful! Thanks again! I will start playing around with Tickz!!